# JMockit with EclEmma code coverage issue

Tags: exception, jmockit, eclemma

Before anyone downvotes me for a duplicate question.... I have read all the other StackOverflow answers related to this topic and nothing has answered my question.

So I am using JMockit 1.19, below is my pom.xml dependencies for Jmockit and Junit

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using EclEmma 2.3.2 plugin as installed via Eclipse Marketplace.

However I am getting several different issues at once when I try to view my code coverage.

For one I get the following exception log:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:99)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1695)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_9dd1198.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:136)
    ... 9 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main"
```

I also get two pop-ups that say....

```
popup 1) - "No coverage data has been collected during this coverage session. Please do not terminate the Java process manually from Eclipse."

pupup 2) - "Error while dumping coverage data (code 5013).  com.mountainminds.eclemma.internal.core.launching.AgentServer"
```

In order to get JMockit to run successfully I am providing the JVM argument

```
-javaagent:C:/Users/vn90614/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.19/jmockit-1.19.jar
```

I think this argument is realted to the issue

Comment: You are using some really old versions for everything (JUnit, JMockit, and EclEmma). Both JaCoCo (the coverage library behind the EclEmma plugin) and JMockit have had fixes and improvements for issues like this, so if you can upgrade to recent versions, there is a good chance it will go away.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for work and I have to use versions  from their repositories. I will see if they can upgrade versions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I FINALLY solved this issue after almost a week of working on this and asking everyone in the office. I had linked another project on my build path and that's what caused this issue. Not only did it affect this but this caused a ton of issues with JMockit, Mockito, and PowerMock functions. Linking projects on your build path WILL cause issues for testing frameworks and code coverage.